# GeckoFX45 How to zoom out browser?

Tags: c#, geckofx

I want to zoom out my GeckoFX instance to this value, but I'm getting error

```
geckoWebBrowser1.GetDocShellAttribute().SetZoomAttribute(34);
```

Error I get

> System.NotImplementedException: 'The method or operation is not
>   implemented.'